# Convert crypto wallet address in lowercase to correct format

Tags: ethereum, bitcoin, ripple, cryptocurrency, tron

I'm collecting many types of cryptocurrency address(e.g btc,trx,eth), but some address are came with address.lowercase . I want to correct them.

In case of ethereum, if I use eip55 in lowercase eth address, I can correct them. But in the other case, I can't.

There are any method to correct them?
Example : rabesxxx7qq1rdboxxzhhjaksyw19jptmt(XRP) -> raBesxXx7QQ1RdboXXZHhjaKSyW19JptMt(correct address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that XRP addresses are base58 encoded, so converting to lowercase is a lossy operation. ("rabesx" and "raBesx" are two different numbers.) I don't see how you can "correct" that.

There is a checksum at the end that can help detect corruptions like this, but there are too many combinations of uppercase/lowercase to try them all until you found a working one.

In short, by the time you've received an address that has been converted to lowercase, it's too late. You need to address the issue with whatever process is giving you these corrupted addresses.

Comment: The problem occurred because the address came in lowercase from the place where the address was collected. If we can't replace lowercase letters with original addresses like ethereum, then there's only one way to change the address collection site. Thanks for your answer:)

Comment: If the letter case of a TRX (base58 format address) is unrecoverable (and I reaaly can't recover it unlike for ETH addresses where letter case is recoverable), why tronscan website can find an address being passed in a lowercase and returns the page with TRX address with the right letter case?

If tronscan can recover the letter case information it is supposed to be possible for others, isn't it?